# Resize image to approximate number of pixels

Tags: php, image-processing, resize

I want to prevent JPG images added to email attachment be 250kB or smaller. I have discovered, that for JPG images, this is very non-linear, so I did some tests and decided that 2000000 pixels is maximum that I can allow.

So now, I need to resize every image to 2000000pixels or a value as close as possible. This sounds quite impossible however:

```
x2*y2 = 2000000
x2/y2 = x/y      //The aspect ratio must be the same
```

So what is the solution for this?

My thoughts about the problem:

1. For `NxN` image, ratio equals to 1.  (`N`=`N` of course)
2. For 9 pixels and ratio 1: `x = y = sqrt(9) = 3`
3. For `NxM` image, where `N!=M` and `M∨N=1` the ratio is either 1/M or N/1. For `p` pixels the image will then have `x=p` `y=1` or vice versa.

From point **3.** I do know that both X and Y are values between `1` and `sqrt(p)`.

Comment: Do you want to reprocess larger images into smaller ones or just prevent the user from uploading them over your size limit?

Comment: Only the larger images shall be resized. And yes, they must be resized, not refused.

Comment: [and so they shall](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I do know how to resize the imags in PHP. As you may have noticed, `imagecopyresized` requires width and height for both images, not just the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all, there is an answer on [another board](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10908/60941) (since you guys here on SO don't do math obviously).

And this is how the program implementation of the equation looks like:

```
function image_resize_to_pixel_count($im, $pixels) {
  $x = imagesx($im);
  $y = imagesy($im);

  $S = $pixels; //I use S here to remind you, that it's analogic to rectangle area

  //Define the coefficient for $x, $y (old image dimensions)
  $h = sqrt($S/($x*$y));

  $x2 = round($h*$x);
  $y2 = round($h*$y);


  //Standard resize to x, y procedure follows from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a random image that has too many pixels and too many bytes for your liking:

```
convert -size 3000x1000 xc:red +noise random image.jpg
```

Check the size, yes, over 10MB

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff  10454067  9 Jan 12:03 image.jpg
```

---

Now, either reduce to 250kB whilst retaining pixel dimensions:

```
convert image.jpg -define jpeg:extent=250k result.jpg
```

Check file size in bytes, yes, now around 250kB:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff    259356  9 Jan 12:08 result.jpg
```

---

Or, reduce pixel dimensions till total number of pixels under 2,000,000:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 2000000@ result.jpg
```

Check dimensions, yes under 2,000,000 pixels and still in same ratio of 3:1

```
identify result.jpg
result.jpg JPEG 1732x1154 1732x1154+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.70352MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

---

See, we can do maths - just slowly!!! What's 5 years?